# AngularUI monthpicker in popup shown as datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the [angular ui datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) in monthpicker-mode as a popup, but it is shown as a datepicker.

I've found a working example of the monthpicker as inline-picker [here](http://codepen.io/jbruni/pen/znLef/), but I need it as a popup.

[Here is a plunker of what I've tried](http://plnkr.co/edit/tLt8LhIsb862Qdwblz5h?p=preview), based on the official example.

Comment: Your plnkr doesn't exists ;)

Comment: it does but plnkr.co seems to be down right now

Answer (score 2):

i managed to fix it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tvte8r1EbjbeDZLn2ivq

The most important thing was that there was an issue with the datepickerMode not being parsed correctly thus the datepicker starting in day-mode instead of month.
I just imported the latest version out of the angular-ui bootstrap repository.

The rest was basically just modifying the dateOptions and setting the datepicker-mode to popupMode.

Hope you're good now ;-)
Cheers, Jan

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntax problems in your code.

the directives max-mode and min-mode will take parameters covered with a single quote. So the proper way should be,

```
<input type="text" show-weeks="false" show-button-bar="false" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" min-mode="'month'" max-mode="'month'" />
```

You can checkout the docs of Angular Bootstrap from [***here***](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and search for DatePicker where the functionalities of ***min-mode*** and ***max-mode*** directives are explained.

For example check this [***demo***](http://plnkr.co/edit/cp6EnSyn5vY08ZwjjDca?p=preview)

[***Note*** : Though it's too late to answer this question, but you may find it helpful]

Comment: This works only with UI-BootStrap 0.13 and above (which depends on Angular 1.3 and above)...