# year and month only datepicker angularjs and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have problem i want to use datepicker from date to date(check in and check out with months not days) and it should be with months ,the problem is: i have template but it show me the the day and the year and the month , what i want is just month and year

this what i get and i want just months and year 
[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/W5pb1boMLOHZFnWkMU8o?p=preview

html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Start</h4>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <p>
            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="start" is-open="startOpened" min="minStartDate" max="maxStartDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
            <button class="btn" ng-click="openStart()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <h4>End</h4>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <p>
            <input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="end" is-open="endOpened" min="minEndDate" max="maxEndDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
            <button class="btn" ng-click="openEnd()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

js :

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.start = new Date('11/20/13');
  $scope.end = new Date();

  $scope.minStartDate = 0; //fixed date
  $scope.maxStartDate = $scope.end; //init value
  $scope.minEndDate = $scope.start; //init value
  $scope.maxEndDate = $scope.end; //fixed date same as $scope.maxStartDate init value

  $scope.$watch('start', function(v){
    $scope.minEndDate = v;
  });
  $scope.$watch('end', function(v){
    $scope.maxStartDate = v;
  });

  $scope.openStart = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.startOpened = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.openEnd = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.endOpened = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
  };
};
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: just add `  $scope.format = 'MM-yyyy'` in your controller

Comment: i tried not working you can edit it it not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***min-mode*** and ***max-mode*** attributes in your date picker element. By setting min-mode to month and max-mode to year you enable month-picker and year-picker only.

***HTML :***

```
<input type="text" show-weeks="false" show-button-bar="false" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" min-mode="'month'" max-mode="'year'" />
```

This should help.

You can also check my answer on this thread where I have enabled the month picker only. ([***similar solution***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180416/angularui-monthpicker-in-popup-shown-as-datepicker/32422520#32422520))

[***demo***](http://plnkr.co/edit/cp6EnSyn5vY08ZwjjDca?p=preview)

Comment: it not working ,the solution you attached , 
i tried to add the button into my solution and not work , 
thanks for helping

Comment: did you try the demo? That's working. Specify what's not working.

Comment: yes it work thanks , but can it save the as month and year please

Comment: change the max-mode to year. It'll take month and year only.